# Pointing documentation for user to connect their Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to create a booking App.
Where user can connect their calendar, where user able:

- Read their calendar -> to see if the time collides with other event
- Write to their calendar -> to save the booking

Can anyone point me to the documentation for this ?
so user can connect their calendar with my app and our system able to read/write ?

Thanks

Comment: I got the authentication for user part https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js

Answer (score 0):

I got the authentication for user part https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js